# Importing functions from other files not working (React)

Tags: reactjs, import, next.js

Import:

```
import { get, set, faviconChange } from '/js/title.js';
```

title.js

```
var geta = a => localStorage.getItem(a)
var seta = (a, b) => localStorage.setItem(a, b)
export function get(a) {
  localStorage.getItem(a);
}
export function set(a,b) {
  localStorage.setItem(a,b);
}
document.title = get('title') || 'Anonymous'
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'icon';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
export function faviconChange(value) {
  set('link', value)
  link.href = get('link') || '/favicon.ico';
  console.log("working " + link.href)
}
link.href = get('link') || '/favicon.ico';
```

Error:

```
./pages/index.js:6:0
Module not found: Can't resolve '/js/title.js'
  4 | import Particles from 'react-tsparticles';
  5 | import { loadFull } from "tsparticles";
> 6 | import { get, set, faviconChange } from '/js/title.js';
  7 | 
  8 | 
  9 | export default function Home() {

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

Whenever I try and import these functions, I get the above error and I've looked it up, and everyone seems to do it this way, yet I get an error. Am I missing something/putting these imports in the wrong file?

Comment: importing paths are relative to the file that is doing the importing. There is a pattern to use a root alias like "@/" which represents the root of your project you may have seen but is not standard and requires additional tech. If your file is located in js/foo.js, then the path to title is `./title.js"

Comment: Do you have a `jsconfig.json` file in your project? Can you show us your folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

Try to import from `'./js/title.js';`

When importing from another file, you must go up in the files hierarchy with a dot `'./'`

Comment: Didnt work and I have no idea why that would work

Comment: I don't know where the file you are trying to import from is located.
Is it in the same folder?

Comment: React/Next.js pages are in the pages folder and static files are in public. So the js is in the public/js folder and settings.js is in pages. However, the routing makes it so that it's portrayed as http://localhost:3000/settings and https://localhost:3000/js/title.js.

Comment: @Gage You should not put your Next.js source code in public/js/. Put it anywhere else outside pages, and import them into your pages using relative paths. You should not be serving any files directly in public/, import/export doesn't even work as standalone files... Next's webpack will generate files and serve them automatically to the client.

Comment: So i should put it in the root? I'm confused, title.js is just a random js file. If im not putting it in public and not in pages, root is the only other place but that just seems weird.

Comment: @Gage, public is strictly for static files like images. Your _source code_ should be imported via the `Next.js` app where it consumes files in `./pages/*`. Just like `pages` is a special folder, so is `public` which exposes the files to the internet. You don't want source code in there. Where else? That's up to you. Just not pages or public. It's pretty common to see things like a `components` (as in react components) directory, styles directory, etc. You can also put `pages` inside `src/` where you can make new folder patterns easily "from scratch"

Answer (score 0):

3 suggestions are here.

**1. adding export in your importing file**

`export default YourFunctionName;`

**2. As @SaF mentioned, make sure the path is correct** 
How?

- If you are using linux/unix/mac use the command `tree` on the parent folder to get the exact path (if windows, you can install `tree`)
- try using `../../../folder_x` to go to folder_x which is 3 folders behind and `./` to get current folder
- try printing your js file's absolute path using fs module https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-js (comment the import line and try this)

**3. Change `jsx` file extention to normal `js`**
and add below code in webpack.config.js to resolve jsx as js

```
 module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  }
};
```

Comment: I forget what the answer was to it, but after a lot of fiddling, it eventually worked (not using any of these suggestions/answers). One of the issues was I was importing from a JS file inside of the public folder, however that was not all of the issues. I will mark as solved since this question is almost a week old now